# How to target text inside an html element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following case generated by a plugin which I am not able to rewrite as I would need to fix this. It generates breadcrumbs for a website like the following example:

```
<li><a>Parent</a></li>
<li><a>Subparent</a></li>
<li><a>Subsubparent</a></li>
<li>Current Site</li>
```

I have styled the links to be clickable more easy

```
li {height: 40px;}
li a {padding: 5px; display: inline-block; height: 30px;}
```

Now of course the last element does not get the same padding and looks wired. I am not able to wrap a html element like `span` around it in php.

Is there a css selector to select the text inside of an element, without affecting the element itself? Or wraps an html element like `span` around it, something like

`li:last-child::before {content:"<span>"}`

Every hint appreciated! [If someone likes jsfiddle here is one to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/ypLn1xk2/4/).

Comment: What's wrong with `li {padding: 5px; display: inline-block;}`? See http://jsfiddle.net/ypLn1xk2/1/

Comment: I missed one important part in my li styling. I have updated my question!

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/ypLn1xk2/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the following work-around to get the right styling.

```
li:last-child::before {
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

li:last-child::after {
    content: ".";
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Sadly one of the both pseudo elements needs `content:"."` or another real content. This is a solution to target spacing (margin/padding) without changing some css/html.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypLn1xk2/5/)

Still I would love to see clean css solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the padding to the last `li` together with the anchors?

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypLn1xk2/2/)

```
li a, li:last-child {padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: I am sorry, my question was not detailed enough. There is an `li {height: 40px}`, which causes problem in displaying the background using `li:last-child`! I have updated my question!

Comment: i guess li:last-child selector wont work if not nested by ul?

Comment: @SMKarthick last-child selectors work although without being nested inside an ul !

Comment: @MarianRick ok. in LcSalazar  code i applied the color to the last child and it ain't works.  http://jsfiddle.net/ypLn1xk2/7/

Comment: @SMKarthick - yes it does get the black text color applied... MarianRick is correct, `:last-child` won't care if it is contained in a `ul`, though using a `li` outside a `ul` is invalid markup

Answer (score 0):

My own suggestion, at its simplest, would be:

```
li {
  height: 40px;
  /* vertically-aligns the text to
       the same 'line': */
  line-height: 40px;
  /* to display in a row, given the
       text-alignment I assume this is required,
       remove/adjust if not: */
  float: left;
  /* removes the bullets: */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Just to clearly show the size of
       the <li> elements: */
  background-color: #ffa;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  /* again, just to show the size: */
  background-color: #f90;
}
li a {
  /* to fill the whole of the <li>: */
  display: block;
}
li a:hover {
  /* just to show the hover 'hit-area': */
  background-color: #f00;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```css
li {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f90;
}
li a {
  display: block;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Subparent</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Subsubparent</a>
  </li>
  <li>Current Site</li>
</ul>
```

Now, to style them as 'breadcrumbs,' you could use generated content to provide
the separators, for example, you can update the CSS:

```
li {
  /* other rules remain the same,
     this is added to provide space
     for the generated content: */
  margin-left: 1em;
}
  /* there is (usually) no marker before
     the first breadcrumb, this removes its
     space: */
li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
/* other rules that, remain the
   same, are excised for brevity */
li::before {
  /* unicode for the guillemot,
     '»', character: */
  content: '\00BB';
  /* to position easily and prevent
     altering the position of the child
     <a> elements: */
  position: absolute;
  /* simple means to move the generated
     content off the left edge: */
  right: 100%;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
/* no marker the first breadcrumb: */
li:first-child::before {
  /* removing both content and width: */
  content: '';
  width: 0;
```

```css
li {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
li a {
  display: block;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
}
li::before {
  content: '\00BB';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
li:first-child::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Subparent</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Subsubparent</a>
  </li>
  <li>Current Site</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey @DavidThomas, thanks for your suggestion. This is a clean css solution and it works great in jsfiddle. But viewing in Safari 8.0.3 the `a {display: block}` only affects the space of the `li` tag **without** its `padding` while viewing my site. Maybe this depends on my reset.css or another tag I am not able to find.

Feel free to test it yourself on http://bit.ly/1zDiS9x (Breadcrumbs are below the navigation)